# Convert & Transform a PHP array variable to JS

Tags: javascript, php, mongodb

I am trying to implement a new way for users to enter data into an HTML form with `Slim Select` JS library.

I have basic functionality working, with a pre-populated list of `<option>` items.

Originally, the PHP code would grab the list of names from a database (now in MongoDB), which is then looped through when the `<select>` element is created.

With `Slim Select`, you can pass in a "data array" as a parameter of the JS script. The manually-created format is this:

```
var jsPlayers2 = [
    {"placeholder": true, "text": "Type Name"},
    {"text": "Ernie Els", "value": "abc1"},
    {"text": "Rory McIlroy", "value": "abc2"},
    {"text": "Tiger Woods", "value": "abc3"}
];
        
new SlimSelect({
    select: '#slim-select',
    data: jsPlayers2, // THIS WOULD BE REPOINTED TO THE JSPLAYERS ARRAY VAR...
    
    onChange: (info) => {
        console.log(info)
    }
})
```

My MongoDB document structure returned currently is:

```
var jsPlayers = [{
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "62b49410e63c2f8469089189"
        },
        "name": "Tiger Woods",
        "clubs": [{
            "clubId": {
                "$oid": "6076030465508936f00e086c"
            },
            "name": "Jupiter FL",
            "nickName": "Jupiter",
            "logoPath": "jupiter.png"
        }]
    }, {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "609d0993906429612483cfb1"
        },
        "name": "Ernie Els",
        "clubs": [{
            "clubId": {
                "$oid": "6076030465508936f00e086c"
            },
            "name": "Wentworth UK",
            "nickName": "Wentworth",
            "logoPath": "wentworth.png"
        }]
    }, ...
}];
```

I have used a simplistic `echo` of this variable into a new JS variable:

```
var jsPlayers = <?php echo json_encode($players); ?>;
```

How can I only pick out the fields I need from within each document? Or is there a way to filter the array elements when I add them to the `slim-select.data` property?

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through your players to create the array you want to output as JSON. Something like this:

```
$options = [];
foreach ($players as $player) {
    $options[] = (object)["text"  => $player->name,
                          "value" => $player->getId()];
}
echo json_encode($options);
```

This only outputs the JSON.

Note that I used `$player->getId()`, which might not work for you. If your players are really objects you might have defined a method yourself to get their id.